# Invalid format error in Jquery validator plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-validate, unobtrusive-validation

I have a textbox for creditcard which is type="number" inputmode="numeric" pattern="d*" to display numeric keypad in android devices

Since I have added this pattern="d*", validation always triggers "Invalid Format" error in Samsung Galaxy devices(added pattern attribute on the fly for devices). After searching on forums, I think I may need to ignore or override pattern validations for this field. All validations are binding using ASP.NET MVC 4 and Unobtrusive validations. There are alot of data-* attributes when loading this input control.

Can anyone tell me how to ignore or override this pattern validations alone?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The jQuery Validate plugin is automatically picking up and using the `pattern` attribute.  If you want to avoid pattern validation, then do not use the `pattern` attribute.

Comment: pattern attribute is required in Android device to bring the numeric keyborad

Comment: Then you're stuck.  There is no workaround.